# What's the purpose of the tag 'code-review-practice'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just noticed the tag [code-review-practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-review-practice). I don't quite understand what the purpose of it is on a SE site which is all about Code Review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed -- I checked most of them and they were just plain code reviews, the "ambient" tag you'd expect every question on this site to have simply because it *exists* here!

That's the very definition of unnecessary...

So, I migrated one about the practice of code review to programmers, and I destroyed the tag elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

In the first few days of the site there were several questions asked about how to conduct code reviews and ended up tagged with that.  We should probably just get rid of it, along with `review` because they just don't make any sense.

Comment: If that's what it's meant to be, that definitly belongs on meta, ... right? :)

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: I suppose it could make sense on meta :)  Definitely not on the main site anymore.